# How do I switch letsencrypt authentication from HTTP to AWS dns-route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am using Certbot and have several domains that I need to switch from HTTP authorization to AWS Route 53.

Both configurations are working fine, but now I need to switch all the certificates to use route 53. Is there a certbot command that does that?

In the config file I see this:

```
[renewalparams]
authenticator = apache
installer = apache
account = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
manual_public_ip_logging_ok = None
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

Comment: The only way I've been able to accomplish this is to delete everything under the /etc/letsencrypt directory and reinstall certbot using pip then requesting the certificates again. I hope there's a better way to do this because I have a lot of domains.

Comment: what do you mean by "*Both configurations are working fine*"? Do you have some domains already authenticated via route53 while others are still authenticating with http? Are all route53 zones accessible from the same AWS account? If yes, you can edit the config files to match the config of the domains already working with route53 (if you have some scripting skills, you should be able to automate this task)

Comment: Or you can do a `--force-renewal` your domains with a new authenticator, so certbot will rewrite the config files for you. Also this can be automated. But if your really have to do it for thousands of domains, you might (?) hit some API limits if you do this within a short period of time ...

Comment: And I found [this thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/multiple-domain-renewal-config-file/18712) in the letsencrypt community forum, where it is mentioned, that the global `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini` takes precedence over the renewal config of the single domains. Maybe, if *all* your domains should be authenticated via route53 you can add your config there.  (Be aware that thread is several years old and behaviour might have changed in the meantime)

Comment: @derpirscher the solution was in cli.ini If you post that as an answer, I'll mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/multiple-domain-renewal-config-file/18712) in the letsencrypt community forum, where it is mentioned, that the global `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini` takes precedence over the renewal config of the single domains. If all your domains should be authenticated via route53 you can add your config there.

Adding /etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini to the server is the trick.

This is a sample file from https://gist.github.com/antillean/8517fba47df25a98100a

```
 This is an example of the kind of things you can do in a configuration file.
# All flags used by the client can be configured here. Run Let's Encrypt with
# "--help" to learn more about the available options.

# Use a 4096 bit RSA key instead of 2048
rsa-key-size = 4096

# Uncomment and update to register with the specified e-mail address
# email = antillean@example.com

# Uncomment and update to generate certificates for the specified
# domains.
# domains = sub.example.com, sub2.example.com, sub3.test.example

# Uncomment to use a text interface instead of ncurses
# text = True

# Uncomment to use the standalone authenticator on port 443
# authenticator = standalone
# standalone-supported-challenges = http-01
```

So for it to work, the changes required were to change authenticator
to

```
authenticator = dns-route53
```

and then perform a sed statement in the /etc/letsencrypt/conf directory to remove the preferred challenges which were HTTP so it will default to the dns-route53 challenge

```
sed -i 's/pref_challs = http-01,//g' *.conf
```

then testing it by running

```
certbot renew
```

and everything worked as desired.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command that "switches" your method of validation.  If you want to ensure that future certificates can be authenticated, you can delete your existing certificates and then run certbot with your R53 configuration.

The other option would be to use `--force-renewal` option if you don't want to delete your existing certificates.

It is important to know that switching from HTTP validation to Route 53 (or any DNS based validation, really) only provides you the ability to create wildcard certificates on your domain.  Once validations occur, the certificate isn't any different (again, with the caveat of issuing wildcard certificates).

Comment: I'm running on a server cluster and the load balancer doesn't always go to the server that's requesting the renewal. If I did it via DNS, it always works.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but @derpirscher had the trick I needed.